# Probe auth on Github with DotNetOpenAuth 3.5.0 library

Tags: dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0, github-api

**Unexpected response Content-Type text/html**

```
DotNetOpenAuth.DLL!DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(bool condition, string message, object[] args) Line 237   C#
        DotNetOpenAuth.DLL!DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.ThrowProtocol(string message, object[] args) Line 257    C#
        DotNetOpenAuth.DLL!DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ChannelElements.OAuth2ClientChannel.ReadFromResponseCore(DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.IncomingWebResponse response) Line 67 + 0x1a4 bytes  C#
        DotNetOpenAuth.DLL!DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.IDirectedProtocolMessage request) Line 659 + 0xe bytes C#
        DotNetOpenAuth.DLL!DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) Line 477 + 0xe bytes  C#
        DotNetOpenAuth.DLL!DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase.UpdateAuthorizationWithResponse(DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState authorizationState, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Messages.EndUserAuthorizationSuccessAuthCodeResponse authorizationSuccess) Line 204 + 0x19 bytes    C#
        DotNetOpenAuth.DLL!DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.HttpRequestInfo request) Line 118 + 0xf bytes    C#
```

Comment: This "question" isn't even phrased as a question.  Please add what your question is, and provide some background, the type of exception thrown, whether you're on a public or local box, who you're talking to, the OAuth 2.0 version of the server you're communicating with...

Comment: http://develop.github.com/p/oauth.html - the server, yes on OAuth 2.0 version supported.
This error occurs both locally and on the hosting.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, either the server is buggy, or it's running an incompatible version of OAuth 2.0 (there are *only* 13 drafts of that unfinalized spec out there in use today).  This is one reason to not use OAuth 2.0 in production until it's finalized.